# How to amend object in an array with duplicate attributes? (XY coordinates)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of objects (nodes) with XY coordinates. Wherever I find a node overlaying another node (with the exact same XY coords) I would like to edit the Y attribute "up" by 3.

id, x, y are all attributes of the objects I am looking at. And collectively held in an Array of nodes.

I am looking to go through the array and whenever a duplicate XY is present, edit the first non-unique instance by adding 3 to the Y attribute. If another duplicate is found, I would like this object's Y attribute to be altered by 6 and so on.

E.g.

```
NODE      X        Y
node1   267555   666777   
node2   267555   666777
node3   245698   656400
node4   267555   666777
```

I would like node 2 and node 4 to become:

```
NODE      X        Y
node1   267555   666777   
node2   267555   666780
node3   245698   656400
node4   267555   666783
```

Essentially adding 3 to 'Y' for every instance of a duplicate XY, and doing so for every instance where there are overlying nodes in the array (the real array is much larger).

I have managed to identify duplicates using, but unsure of how to proceed:

```
duplicates = nodes.group_by{|i| [i.x, i.y] }.select{|k,v| v.length > 1}.values
```

However I don't want a new array, I wish to amend the original "nodes" array attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by creating a class of nodes.

```
class Nodes
  attr_accessor :name, :x, :y
  def initialize(name, x, y)
    @name = name
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
end
```

Next, create the instances shown in the problem.

```
nodes = [
  Nodes.new("node1", 267555, 666777),
  Nodes.new("node2", 267555, 666777),
  Nodes.new("node3", 245698, 656400),
  Nodes.new("node4", 267555, 666777)
]
  #=> [#<Nodes:0x00005c7949ee8e40 @name="node1", @x=267555, @y=666777>,
  #    #<Nodes:0x00005c7949f57c50 @name="node2", @x=267555, @y=666777>,
  #    #<Nodes:0x00005c7949f57958 @name="node3", @x=245698, @y=656400>,
  #    #<Nodes:0x00005c7949f577a0 @name="node4", @x=267555, @y=666777>]
```

Now modify the `y` values as desired. For this we make use of the form of the method [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument called the *default value*. If a hash `h` has been created this way, `h[k]` will return the default value if it does not have a key `k`. This is sometimes called a *counting hash*.

```
nodes.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |inst,h|
  y = inst.y
  inst.y += 3 * h[y] if h.key?(y) 
  h[y] += 1
end
  #=> {666777=>3, 656400=>1}
```

Let's see what `nodes` looks like now.

```
nodes
  #=> [#<Nodes:0x00005c7949ee8e40 @name="node1", @x=267555, @y=666777>,
  #    #<Nodes:0x00005c7949f57c50 @name="node2", @x=267555, @y=666780>,
  #    #<Nodes:0x00005c7949f57958 @name="node3", @x=245698, @y=656400>,
  #    #<Nodes:0x00005c7949f577a0 @name="node4", @x=267555, @y=666783>] 

nodes.map { |inst| [inst.name, inst.x, inst.y] }
  #=> [["node1", 267555, 666777],
  #    ["node2", 267555, 666780],
  #    ["node3", 245698, 656400],
  #    ["node4", 267555, 666783]]
```

Comment: That's ideal, I gave it a whirl and on first glance it appeared to do what I was after perfectly. I then noticed some nodes that had no overlying nodes were also being shunted up due to it only looking at the Y attribute. In attempting to fix this I tried editing it to

`x = inst.x
      y = inst.y
      inst.y += 3 * h[x+y] if h.key?(x+y) 
      h[x+y] += 1`
which seemed to do the trick for the most part. But was still finding some nodes with no overlying nodes being shunted up - unsure why.

Comment: At the moment if I perform the above only on all nodes present within the "duplicates" from the OP it will ignore the nodes  in question which had no overlying nodes yet were still being shunted. Still curious as to why they were still being moved though!

Thank you for your time and answer again, Cary.

Comment: Can you give me an example of data that has the behaviour you describe?

Comment: Hi Cary, had another crack today and it was my silly mistake that caused some nodes to be shunted that didn't have overlying nodes. Using (x+y) obviously solves as a sum when my intention was to combine the X+Y as a string to ensure it would be looking for nodes that had the same X and Y, rather than just the Y.

Initially when using the "x+y" there was 2 nodes overlying with the coordinates (x=267555, y=666777), and another node (x=267605, y=666727) with no overlying nodes. Adding those XYs in each coordinate solves for "934332". 

Simply adding "to_s" helped: `x = inst.x.to_s`.